# is it possible to use handlebars expression to set div's id?

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, marionette, zingchart

I am trying to reuse a template for my ZingChart. The template is very simple

```
<h4>{{title}}</h4>
<div id={{templateId}} class="zingChart"></div>
```

Unfortunately, it looks like ZingChart framework requires that the div have a id attached to it, so I am trying to set it via a handlebars expression similar to setting the {{title}} in the line above my ZingChart div. I can't set the id to something, as only 1 chart will show.

is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Are you passing `templateId` from context object along with `title`? Because handlebars expects it in the context object. Please share your context object if possible.

Answer (score 1):

To set an attribute in handlebars like that you need to use something called bind-attr, like this:

```
<div {{bind-attr id=templateId}} class="zingChart"></div>
```

More reading on this can be found here: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/binding-element-attributes/